# Getting index from two-dimentional array by click. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button

I wonder if there is any way to get index from 2-dimentional array by this way in WPF.

```
bt[i, j].Click += Button_Click;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button) ???
}
```

How can i get i,j of button that i clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways.

If the button click handler is in the same class as the buttons could you search for it?

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < count; j++)
    if (bt[i, j] == sender)
    {
      // found it
    }
```

Or you can set the Tag of the button.

```
bt[i, j].Click += Button_Click;
bt[i, j].Tag = Tuple.Create(i, j);
```

Another is to create a closure for the click handler.

```
private Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> Button_Click(int i, int j)
{
    return (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        (sender as Button) ???
    };
}

bt[i, j].Click += Button_Click(i, j);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are very helpful. :)